# Symfony2: Retrieving user credentials from test config

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I'm doing some functional testing in my Symfony2 app, and want to assert controller security by checking that only users with appropriate roles can access my controller actions. I've set up two users with different roles, that authenticate with basic credentials:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        users:
            basic: { password: basic, roles: ROLE_BASIC }
            admin: { password: admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I don't want to hard-code these users into every test I write (I'll be writing lots). Ideally I'd like to get the details of the users I've defined in my config from the container. Is this possible? I.E. instead of doing this:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/inventory/index', array(), array(), 
    array(
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin',
        'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'admin'
    ));
```

I want to do this:

```
// Get the user details from the container
$users = $this->container->get('something');
$user = $users['admin'];

$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/inventory/index', array(), array(), 
    array(
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => $user->getUsername(),
        'PHP_AUTH_PW' => $user->getPassword()
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [LiipFunctionalTestBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle), specifically the base `WebTestCase` class, [here](https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/master/Test/WebTestCase.php#L229).

I haven't used this bundle personally, but it claims to account for authentication from within your test cases.

**Update**

You might be better off loading the Users as fixtures rather than in-memory . If you aren't using a database, setup `LiipFunctionalTestBundle` to use SQLite. This way you can have access to each User from within your tests.

Also, although probably not recommended, you can alter `liip_functional_test.authentication` any time by doing something like this:

```
$this->getContainer()->setParameter('liip_functional_test.authentication', 'new_value');
```

Comment: Thanks - I've tried that bundle (I'm actually using it for test database caching) but it doesn't really solve my problem. It does let me specify the user to authenticate as in the config file via a 'liip_functional_test.authentication' parameter. However since I intend to make requests with a lot of different users, each with different roles, it doesn't solve my problem - ideally I need access to all user credentials within my test class, though I guess I could follow their lead and just duplicate the details as a custom setting for my bundle.

Comment: I'd hoped to achieve this without using fixtures because I didn't want to add any more overhead to each test, which are already slower than I'd like. It is a viable last resort though, I'll try the YAML approach suggested by @Florian first and if that doesn't work out I'll go for fixtures. Thanks!

Comment: You could always just use one user and add/remove roles from it.

Comment: Ended up using fixtures, following an approach similar to https://gist.github.com/1223886. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a test environment and don't want to dive into complex stuff, the **really** easiest way is to parse the file containing your in-memory provider using the Yaml parser, and use it to feed your client requests.

Using the LiipFunctionalTestBundle would force you to define one and **only** one user to connect with.
Moreover, it would force you to duplicate this information, once in your security providers section and once in your DI parameters.

The last option is to define your own service that uses private security services to configure itself. This is far more complex and less maintanable than a simple yaml parsing :).

Comment: Parsing the YAML does sound like it's going to be the quickest and easiest option, even if I'd hoped for something more integrated. I'll give it a go, thanks!

Comment: This approach did what I initially wanted to do, but as I wrote more tests I realised that I'd eventually need to use actual users, so I ended up using fixtures. Thanks for the help though!